# In Python, why do function parameters maintain their value beetween function calls

Tags: python

I'm fairly new at Python and i cannot wrap my head around the results im getting
Using the code below:

```
def func(a,b=set()):
    res=list()
    for i in a:
        if i not in b:
            res.append(i)
            b|={i}
    return res

print(func([1,1,2,2,3,4]))
print(func([1,1,2,2,3,4]))
```

I was getting output:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[]
```

I put "print(b)" above "res=list()" and got output:

```
set()
[1,2,3,4]
{1,2,3,4}
[]
```

What is going on? Shouldn't "b" be set to "set()" when i call the function? Im using Python 3.6

Comment: Have a read of the important warning herehttps://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) for default parameters:

> The default value is evaluated only once. This makes a difference when the default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or instances of most classes.

When you define a function with a default parameter, the default value is only evaluated when the definition is first executed by the interpreter (the actual `def` statement). This is usually not a problem, except for when a mutable default value is used. That is to say, one that can be modified in place.

In your case, when you modify `b` in your function the first time you call it, it keeps that value the next time around. To avoid this, you can do like so:

```
def func(a,b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = set()
    res=list()
    for i in a:
        if i not in b:
            res.append(i)
            b|={i}
    return res
```

Now `b` will always have the default value you want.

Answer (score 2):

In python functions are objects and arguments are evaluated and executed once. this is a nice explanation : http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

in your example, it could be "fixed" by doing:

```
def func(a,b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = set()
    res=list()
    for i in a:
        if i not in b:
            res.append(i)
            b|={i}
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

In First function call b is empty
See here

[image]

In second function call b is already fill with element
[image]

So this condition not run `if i not in b` and return empty list

Try this

```
def func(a):
    res=list()
    b=set()
    for i in a:
        if i not in b:
            res.append(i)
            b|={i}
    return res

print(func([1,1,2,2,3,4]))
print(func([1,1,2,2,3,4]))
```

Output

> [1, 2, 3, 4]
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4]